# How to maintain page state?

Tags: flutter, navigationbar, statefulwidget, flutter-go-router

I am using `Flutter 3` and `go_router v10.0.0` to develop a program.

This program uses the bottomNavigationBar(PageA, PageB, PageC), I hope that after these pages are routed back and forth, the pages can still maintain their state.
For example, pageA is a ListView, and now a lot of data has been loaded. When I return to pageA from page B or C, pageA is still what I left at that time.

I realized this function by querying the document(https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/main/packages/go_router/example/lib/stateful_shell_route.dart).

Now I use `TabBarView` in PageA, and each View is still a page that loads `ListView` through the network.

The problem now is: I wrote these codes and put them in them, but their state can't be maintained, and they will be reloaded every time I switch `TabBarView` pages.

How can I solve this problem?
I have checked a lot of posts, which are either useless or out of date.
If there is a simpler way to deal with it, I can give up using `go_router`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the state of the pages using mixin called **AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin**:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  
  @override
  // TODO: implement wantKeepAlive
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true; //this needs to be true

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);

    return Scaffold();
  }
}
```

Do this for all Page A, B and C. Once loaded their state will be kept alive. Read this [ARTICLE](https://medium.com/manabie/flutter-simple-cheatsheet-4370a68f98b3) for better example.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `PageStorageKey`. It will maintain the state